# How do I get a button to identify itself?

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas

**Adobe Animate CC, HTML5 Canvas.**

I have a few buttons that I'm trying to set up dynamically - set the text on each one, set their colors, etc. One thing I can't seem to figure out is how to get these buttons to do stuff to themselves when moused-over or clicked.

In this block of code, I just want a button to change the text on itself when moused-over. What am I missing?

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);

function fl_MouseOverHandler(event) {
    event.target.theTitle.text = "You moused-over me!"
}

for (a=0; a<11; a++) {

    this.container["button"+a].theTitle.text = "Button Number "+ a;
    this.container["button"+a].addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);
}
```

Comment: get rid of ".text". the property of tooltips is just "element.title". the rest looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the `theTitle` attribute is, and I guess this is wrong. Try:

```
event.target.textContent = 'You moused-over me!'
```

`this` refers in a listener to the object you're listening, so the button that has been hovered in this case. So you can just do `this.innerText = 'whatever'`

A [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/math2001/g75qbdgo/)

Hope it helped

Matt

Comment: Note that `innerText` is a *non-standard property* - `textContent` is the standardized (not quite the same though) alternative

Comment: @JaromandaX: maybe, but firefox finally supports it as of v45, so it should be relatively compatible (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)

Comment: yes, I am aware of that - did you read the big fat warning *This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. **Do not use it on production sites facing the Web** it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future*

Comment: Okay, some progress toward my goal... Thanks! 

How can I set properties of movieclips INSIDE the target? When I try to do that, my console tells me "TypeError: event.target.buttonColor is undefined"